# Would it be possible to bioengineer a new type of creature?

Tags: biology, bioengineering

Would it be possible (with advanced DNA coding and manipulation technology) to bioengineer a new type of creature with certain desired traits?  One such creature I’m curious about would be a large insect or reptile-like creature that would be used for combat.  (Not all creatures made with this technology would be used for combat just to clarify).  Could this bioengineered creature be a hybrid between reptile and insect?  Or would it have to fall solidly into one of those two categories?  It’s hide would by plated with hard plates that are resistant to many forms of weapons.

Comment: With our technology, or sf-level technology?

Comment: @nearsighted With sf-level technology.

Comment: @nearsighted I clarified that point in my question, thank you! 

Comment: The question for me is: if you've got the DNA design technology to make all this possible, and you want to use it "for combat", why not just design a virus? Of course there are many possible valid answers to this question, but as it'd be far easier and more efficient to do so, you'll probably have to explain this too.

Comment: How do you define what makes a creature meaningful distinct? Without knowing that we cannot say whether it's possible to create a new type of creature or not. In your world you get to define where that line is.

Comment: @sphennings  I said in the question some kind of hybrid between reptile and insect, not necessarily having to fall squarely into either of those categories.  So not a reptile, not an insect, but a creature that has elements from both and doesn’t cleanly fall into either category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes and No

But mostly no: transferring genes between species is tricky. Take, for instance, these [Chinese scientists who gave mice genes from deer to produce antlers.](https://www.iflscience.com/mini-antlers-grown-on-mice-heads-after-scientists-implant-deer-cells-67977) They are most definitely *not* functional antlers. Much to my inner child's disappointment, we are not getting the mouse version of jackalopes anytime soon.

This being said, some gene transfer works. Glowing lab mice, cats, and others are a good example of this. It all depends on what you are modifying and how.

Just remember that genes are not computer code. You cannot rip any gene out and paste it into a genome and expect there to be no problems. Transferring a gene can get you glowing cats or a horrible mutant which cannot live outside of the womb.

## We Modify Existing Creatures

As far as I know, we only modify existing creatures. We do not have the command of genetics and cellular processes yet to build a creature "from the ground up."

So near sci-fi technology would have to take a base creature and heavily modify it. We have been doing that with selective breeding for quite a while and have only now gotten to speeding up that process via gene manipulation. It is still an active frontier of human knowledge and seems like it will go on for a very, very long time.

## Body Plans Have Limits

There is also the issue of body plans having limits. Insects can only get so big because of available oxygen and their capacity to get resources to their cells. Lizards, with those fancy lungs and closed circulatory systems, can get much bigger.

As far as I know, there isn't anything against introducing scutes (bony plates) onto this like monitor lizards and then breeding them to be especially bloodthirsty. You run into the usual lizard issues of being cold-blooded, not very social, and not particularly smart (compared to mammals and birds). There are no free lunches!

Comment: "Just remember that genes are not computer code. You cannot rip any gene out and paste it into a genome and expect there to be no problems."

To be fair, that's true for not very well-organised computer code too :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes with sufficient technology and resources, but it'd be a challenge. Hybrids would probably be harder than changing simpler genes, like for fur color. If it's important for the story, I'd say go ahead, with a bit of research.